# Show text in iOS notification center (Swift)?

Tags: ios, swift, nsnotificationcenter

How am I able to show text in the notification center (drop down menu) in iOS using Swift?

Like this:

[image]

Comment: That isn't a notification - it is a today extension - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/NotificationCenter.html

Comment: Here is something  about userNotification: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSUserNotification_Class/index.html